# Is this an homage to Trading Places?

Tags: reference, trading-places, unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt

In episode 6 of Unbreakable Kimmy there is a scene where the rich daughter's friends are sat around a fountain (at about 18:30 into the episode) and a girl says

> ['and she stepped on the ball'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh4GciP8zfM#t=18m30s)
>   [image]

and starts laughing, the manner of how she said this very reminiscent of this scene from Trading Places:

Is this a sendup/homage to this scene as it's mocking the rich and vapid society group?

Comment: Seems likely. Other people think the same (like [this one](http://www.medialifemagazine.com/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt-a-hoot/)). But not sure how we can prove it for now.

Comment: @Walt thanks for that link, at least I don't think it's just me that thought this.

Comment: @Walt - The link you provide ties it back to *Trading Places* and from there back to *Auntie Mame* ... It says towards the bottom of the writ, *At one point, when the show cuts to a group of Xanthippe’s rich friends, one of them is heard saying, “And she stepped on the ball!” That’s a reference to another three-decade-old movie, “Trading Places,” which adapted the line from the 1958 movie “Auntie Mame.”* That seems about as golden as anything you're going to find.

Comment: I mainly meant it's too early to find comments from the creators. It's a very recent episode of a new show.

Comment: I think the line was delivered more like the way it was delivered by the Gloria character in the 1958 movie Auntie Mame. Perhaps I just like the idea of it being a homage to that movie.

Comment: The line is also used in Showtimes' Billions. However, the character says: "and she steps on the billiard ball"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's safe to say by now that **this is indeed an intentional homage** as it's not only mentioned in several TV sites (like [this](http://www.medialifemagazine.com/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidt-a-hoot/) or [this](http://www.tvinsider.com/article/931/unbreakable-kimmy-schmidts-hidden-gems-jokes-you-may-have-missed/) and also [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/UnbreakableKimmySchmidt)), but it's also now [on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3339966/trivia):

> In Episode 6, Xanthippe's female friend is finishing a story with the punchline "...and then she stepped on the ball." This line, the context and the pompous "Yuppie-esque" delivery, are borrowed from a similar scene in "Trading Places" (1983). Which in turn borrowed it from [Auntie Mame](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051383/combined), the Rosilind Russell classic from the 50s.

It's both a thematic allusion (Xanthippe's hipster-looking friends are really no less preppy and snobbish than the ones in *Trading Places*) and a pop-culture reference that's expected from [a Tina Fey series](http://www.avclub.com/article/watch-every-movie-reference-em30-rock-emever-made-96117) - especially when it's from a classic 80s comedy that featured SNL members so prominently.